# The getter 'user' isn't defined for the type 'SignUppage'. Try importing the library that defines 'user',

Tags: flutter

hi I  have stateful class and I want to call the usercredential that appears in  Stream I want to call it in the main.dart but it appear to me that it is undefined anyone can help me please

this is the stateful class

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:insight_software/models/user.dart';
import 'package:insight_software/widgets/input_file.dart';

class SignUppage extends StatefulWidget {
  SignUppage({key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SignUppage> createState() => _SignUppageState();
}

class _SignUppageState extends State<SignUppage> {
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  String? myemail = '';
  String? mypassword = '';
  String? myconPassword = '';

  GlobalKey<FormState> formstate = new GlobalKey<FormState>();

  UserModel? _userFromFirebaseUser(User userCredential) {
    return userCredential != null ? UserModel(id: userCredential.uid) : null;
  }

  Stream<UserModel?> get userCredential {
    return auth
        .authStateChanges()
        .map((userCredential) => _userFromFirebaseUser(userCredential!));
  }

  Future SignUp() async {
    var formdata = formstate.currentState;

    if (formdata!.validate()) {
      print("valid");
      formdata.save();
      try {
        UserCredential userCredential =
            await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                email: myemail!, password: mypassword!);
        return userCredential;
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
        if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
          print('The password provided is too weak.');
        } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
          print('The account already exists for that email.');
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    } else {}
  }
```

and this is the main.dart

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:insight_software/models/user.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'Screens/intro_screen.dart';
import 'Screens/login_screen1.dart';
import 'Screens/main_screens.dart';
import 'Screens/sign_up_screen.dart';
import 'Screens/sign_up_screen2.dart';
import 'package:insight_software/Screens/sign_up_screen.dart';


Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 
 
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  final Future<FirebaseApp> _initialization = Firebase.initializeApp();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _initialization,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        // Check for errors
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          //return SomethingWentWrong();
        }
        // Once complete, show your application
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return StreamProvider<UserModel?>.value(
            value: SignUppage.userCredential,
            initialData: ,
            child: MaterialApp(
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              title: 'Insight application',
              theme: ThemeData(
                primaryColor: Colors.blue,
                primarySwatch: Colors.lightBlue,
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                dividerColor: Colors.black,
                visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
                textTheme: TextTheme(
                  headline1: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 30,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  headline2: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 22,
                      color: Colors.black.withAlpha(160),
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  headline3: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white.withAlpha(140)),
                  headline4: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                ),
                inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
                  // fill the buttons with colors
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Color(0xfff2f9fe),

                  // three modes for the input buttons email and password
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade800),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                  ),
                  disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade800),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                  ),
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade800),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              home: introScreen(),
              //connect the inrtoScreen with login screen
              routes: {
                // go from the iintro screen to the login screen
                'login': (context) => loginScreen(),
                'sign up': (context) => SignUppage(),
                'continue': (context) => SignUppage2(),
                'sign up new account': (context) => MainScreen(),
              },
            ),
          );
        };
        return Text("Loading");
      },
    );
  }
}
```

it is appears to me undefined in this line in the main

```
value: SignUppage.userCredential,
```

please help me quickly any one can know the answer please

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 reasons why you can't call `userCredential`.

Number 1 is that `userCredential` is not a variable inside `SignupPage`. It's a variable inside `_SignupPageState`. Those two are different. In order to use this variable, you need to move it to the other class. You also have to move the `auth` variable as you need that in order to create the stream.

If you, by any chance want to use the `userCredential` inside the state class, you should call it using the `widget` variable, like this: `widget.userCredential`.

The second problem is that you are trying to access it from outside the class as if it was a static variable, your variable is **not** static, but I can't seem to find any reason why it shouldn't be, so you should add the `static` keyword:

```
static FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
static Stream<UserModel?> get userCredential { ... }
```

Now I said earlier that you should use `widget.userCredential` if you ever want to access it from inside the state class, this is no longer true, now you should do this everywhere `SignupPage.userCredential`.

Final note, I think you should consider moving all this auth related code to a class of it's own and have the signup page call it, but this is not necesary.